# Unmet Peer Dependency angular 2.3.0 rxjs zone.js

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I keep having unmet peer dependencies of `rxjs` and `zone.js`. Even when I removed my `node_modules` folder, cleaned npm cache and reinstalled it.

My node version is 6.7.0, npm version is 3.10.8.

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "bingel-teacher",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Bingel project",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack/webpack.dev.js --inline --hot --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8080",
    "build": "rimraf build && webpack --config webpack/webpack.build.js",
    "test": "karma start",
    "update": "npm install"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 4.2.1",
    "npm": ">= 3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "6.5.3",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "0.3.2",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "4.0.1",
    "css-loader": "0.26.1",
    "file-loader": "0.9.0",
    "gulp-sass": "2.3.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.24.1",
    "imports-loader": "0.6.5",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "karma": "1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage": "1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.0.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "1.0.2",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "0.3.7",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.26",
    "karma-webpack": "1.8.0",
    "node-sass": "3.13.0",
    "phantomjs-polyfill": "0.0.2",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "2.1.13",
    "postcss-loader": "1.2.0",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.8",
    "rimraf": "2.5.4",
    "sass-loader": "4.0.2",
    "string-replace-webpack-plugin": "0.0.4",
    "style-loader": "0.13.1",
    "ts-loader": "1.3.1",
    "tslint": "4.0.2",
    "tslint-loader": "3.3.0",
    "typescript": "2.1.4",
    "typings": "2.0.0",
    "url-loader": "0.5.7",
    "webpack": "1.14.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "1.16.2",
    "webpack-merge": "1.0.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.3.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.3.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.3.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.3.0",
    "@angular/router": "3.3.0",
    "@ngrx/core": "1.2.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "2.2.1",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.21",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "bootstrap-sass": "3.3.7",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "create-reducer-tree": "0.0.7",
    "deep-freeze": "0.0.1",
    "es6-promise": "4.0.5",
    "es7-reflect-metadata": "1.6.0",
    "exports-loader": "0.6.3",
    "flatpickr": "2.2.4",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "imports-loader": "0.6.5",
    "jasmine": "2.5.2",
    "jquery": "3.1.1",
    "lodash": "4.17.2",
    "mdi": "1.7.22",
    "moment": "2.17.1",
    "ng2-translate": "4.2.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-rc.4",
    "snapsvg": "0.4.0",
    "ts-helpers": "1.1.2",
    "zone": "0.3.4",
    "zone.js": "0.7.2"
  }
}
```

My thanks in advance!

Comment: as far as i know you should use `zone.js@0.7.1`. But you shouldn't worry too much about this. If it works, it works

Comment: try "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12", with 
   
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23"

Comment: I don't like the errors, but yes, it does work.

@anshuVersatile : I have tried older versions, but I keep seeing the unmet dependency errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. It was caused by `angular2-in-memory-web-api`. Removing this package fixed the unmet peer dependency errors.

Answer (score 2):

To test, I created a new project with `ng new`, deleted the `node_modules`, replaced `package.json` with the version you supplied and ran `npm install`.

I instantly recreated your problem.

To fix it:

```
npm update
```

This worked fine. The conventional way to solve the peer dependency issues, is to simply install them all. For your example:

```
npm install --save rxjs@5.0.0-rc.4 zone.js@0.7.2
```

Comment: Hi Cobus, this did not work. I removed my node_modules folder, did npm cache clean, and npm update. Still seeing the errors :(

Comment: And did you try installing the dependencies separately?