# Unmet peer dependency webpack@3.6.0

Tags: npm, webpack, webpack-dev-server, npm-install, sass-loader

I am trying to run npm install on a project and it is unable to resolve webpack package. I have followed most of the other questions answers found in google and on here.

I have completely cleaned computer of nodejs + npm files, again  by following answers on here :
[How to completely remove node.js from Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711240/how-to-completely-remove-node-js-from-windows#20711410)
[Unmet Peer Dependency angular 2.3.0 rxjs zone.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41060769/unmet-peer-dependency-angular-2-3-0-rxjs-zone-js#42297654)

I have tried to install the unmet dependencies manually, globally, persisting it to the package.json with npm install --save. Installing the specific versions it asks for and then also the latest versions.

The error that I have is:
    UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY webpack@3.6.0

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 
(node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for 
fsevents@1.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"a
ny"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN sass-loader@4.1.1 requires a peer of webpack@^2 || ^2.2.0-rc.0 || 
^2.1.0-beta || ^1.12.6 but none was install
ed.
PS C:\Users\david.maceachern\Projects\ia_beta\impacttool\src\ui> npm install 
--save webpack
angular-phonecat@0.0.0 
C:\Users\david.maceachern\Projects\ia_beta\impacttool\src\ui
`-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY webpack@3.6.0

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 
(node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for 
fsevents@1.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"a
ny"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN sass-loader@4.1.1 requires a peer of webpack@^2 || ^2.2.0-rc.0 || 
^2.1.0-beta || ^1.12.6 but none was install
ed.
npm ERR! code 1
```

Answer (score 7):

I solved this issue by reading about peer dependencies https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/peer-dependencies/, and proceeding to clean up my package.json fixing the versions so that npm install would not install a version with major breaking changes.

I identified the correct versions by checking the release notes on github of packages that appeared in the npm error.